# Transform x509 private certificate to public

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, pki

I wondering how I can transform X509 certificate with the private key to the public one that I can send to the clients.

For example, I have X509 certificate `full.crt` which was generated using let's encrypt certbot.

[image: Cert details]

Answer (score 1):

Feel my self stupid, but private key and certificate were just concatenated in one file it was really easy to split them.